# How to use xml-rpc in .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xml-rpc

We need to talk with an API using the xml-rpc protocol. We have to use .NET Core 6. How can we do this? It seems all available packages are deprecated?

Comment: Did you try to use XmlRpcCs?

Comment: @FatihKara latest release 2003 so it's not working on my version 6?