# MAUI and XML-RPC

Tags: maui, xml-rpc

Could someone advise me resources for creating MAUI mobile app with connection to a PHP backend throug XmlRpc, please?

I found these pages but these fairly old:

- [XmlRpcNET](https://github.com/marcosbozzani/xmlrpcnet)
- [Kveer.XmlRPC](https://Kveer.XmlRPC)

Comment: There is already a question regarding xml rpc client [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72733671/3593970). Given the lack of response and the age and other issues of the protocol, I don't think there is going to be much for .net standard. Probably write your own.